# Watermarking Image using Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, watermark

I'am trying to watermark an image however iam not able to do so without pasting the watermark with its background color. (see below example)

I tried to implement the tutorial from the following [website](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2017/10/17/how-to-watermark-your-photos-with-python/).

As can be seen from below images, the Current outcome shows watermark with its black background which is not desirable. (See expected outcome image for required result)

I'am using Linux/Ubuntu 20.04 with Python 3.8

Here is the content:

**Background Image**:

[image]

**Watermark Image**:

[image]

**Current Outcome**:

[image]

**Expected Outcome**:

[image]

**Current Outcome after making watermark transparent**:

[image]

Below is code i have used which is same as website tutorial example.

```py
#adding transparency to watermark image(as suggested)
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
img = Image.open('path_to_watermark').convert('RGBA')
img.putalpha(130) 
img.save('path_to_watermark')


def watermark_with_transparency(input_image_path, output_image_path, watermark_image_path, position):
    base_image = Image.open(input_image_path).convert('RGBA')
    watermark = Image.open(watermark_image_path).convert('RGBA')
    width, height = base_image.size
    transparent = Image.new('RGBA', (width, height), (0,0,0,0))
    transparent.paste(base_image, (0,0))
    transparent.paste(watermark, position, mask=watermark)
    transparent.show()
    transparent.save(output_image_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = 'path_to_input_image /home/...'
    watermark_with_transparency(img, 'path_to_output', 'path_to_watermark', position=(0,0))
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your watermark image needs to have transparency.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated question with code and outcome as per your suggestion. However still something to be added(see new pic above).

Comment: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-putalpha

Comment: Let me make it more clear: The watermark image need to have transparent areas *in the file*. This is a problem to solve in an image editing program, not in code.

Answer (score 2):

```
from PIL import Image

background = Image.open("test1.png")
foreground = Image.open("test2.png")

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
background.show()
```

The first parameter to `.paste()` is the image to paste. Second, are coordinates, and the secret sauce is the third parameter. It indicates a mask that will be used to paste the image. If you pass an image with transparency, then the alpha channel is used as the mask.

Check the [docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.paste).

Answer (score 1):

You are pasting an Image with no transparency in it.
Being a PNG, it doesn't mean it contains transparency, but an alpha layer, in which case, every pixel is equal to 255

There is no need to make it transparent with putalpha, you just need a PNG file with the black area transparent